# Cannot find java.exe when run from a .bat file launched via VBA

Tags: java, vba, batch-file, 32bit-64bit, wow64

I have a `script.bat` which looks like this:

```
c:\windows\system32\java.exe -version
pause
```

If I run the script from a command window, it works fine, and outputs the Java version information:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

However, I also have a VBA macro in Excel that calls the same script:

```
Shell "C:\users\Matt\script.bat", vbNormalFocus
```

The `.bat` file executes, but it has a problem finding Java:

```
C:\Users\Matt\Documents>c:\windows\system32\java.exe -version
'c:\windows\system32\java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong? Oddly, this works fine on a number of other machines, just fails on this one laptop (64-bit Windows 7, using Excel 2010).

Comment: Weird. I can reproduce this!

Comment: Additionally, if the directory containing "java.exe" is in the PATH variable, simply calling "java -version" in the batch file works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be the same problem as described here:

http://betterlogic.com/roger/2011/04/cannotunable-to-run-java-exe-from-cwindowssystem32/

Namely, Windows was trying to do [some 64-bit compatibility magic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187) to redirect `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\java.exe`, but Java didn't install a suitable exe in that location.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by copying the exe's of my java1.7 64 bit installation from C:\Windows\system32 and pasting them into C:\Windows\SysWOW64. I don't know if this will work for other versions of java and it shouldn't need to be done with the 32 bit java installation. Using this method the path environment variables do not need to be updated or maintained.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you must have installed java by unzipping the binary.

The path is set correctly because it runs on command line but not when you give full path. Run the below command to get the java.exe directory.

```
c:\> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

Comment: No, I didn't install Java by unzipping anything.